# How to calculate cost per every day(cost hotel + cost flight) depending on flight date?

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database, database-normalization, erd

**Problem**

**How to calculate cost per every day(cost hotel + cost flight) depending on flight date ?**

I need to make database design relations   to  calculate cost per tour for tourists in Egypt .
Flight  cost + hotel cost(room cost + service) per every day for person based on flight date

Suppose I have flight on date 23/06/2017 from Amsterdam to Egypt

And from Cairo to Amsterdam in 26/06/2017 will return back

So that calculation will be as following  :

```
Table tour
1   Tour 1
2   Tour 2
3   Tour 3

Table Tour Duration
Tour 1  3 days
Tour 2  6 days
```

Table Tour Duration Details

```
Day          flight                           Hotel
Day 1      Amsterdam to Cairo                 Hilton
Day 2   Cairo to Aswan                        Hilton
Day 3  Cairo to Amsterdam
```

From 23/06/2017 to 26/06/2017

```
Table cost Per day
Day1     500       25    
Day2   300      25
Day3  500  

Table fligh data 
Tour1   23/06/2017  26/06/2017  1350
Tour2  01/07/2017   07/07/2017 1425 (5 * 25 + 1300)
```

25 represent  cost accommodation per night in hilton hotel .
500 represent cost  flight from Cairo Amsterdam ,Amsterdam to Cairo .

300  represent cost per flight from Cairo to Aswan .

**How to design table relations to calculate cost per every day(cost hotel + cost flight) depending on flight date ?**

```
**sql script**
SE [NileTravel]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[ActivityType]    Script Date: 23/06/2017 1:21:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ActivityType](
    [ActivityTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ActivityType] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ProductID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ActivityType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ActivityTypeID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AirLine]    Script Date: 23/06/2017 1:21:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AirLine](
    [AirLineID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AirLineName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AirLine] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AirLineID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[ChildrenDiscount]    Script Date: 23/06/2017 1:21:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ChildrenDiscount](
    [ChildrenDiscountID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProductID] [int] NULL,
    [MinAge] [int] NULL,
    [MaxAge] [int] NULL,
    [Discount] [money] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ChildrenDiscount] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ChildrenDiscountID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Destination]    Script Date: 23/06/2017 1:21:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Destination](
    [BestimID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BestimName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ParentID] [int] NULL,
    [Image] [varbinary](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Bestiming] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [BestimID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[DurationDetails]    Script Date: 23/06/2017 1:21:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DurationDetails](
    [DetailsDurationID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PackageDurationsID] [int] NULL,
    [Days] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Flight] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Accomodate] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Excursion] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Transfer] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DurationDetails] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DetailsDurationID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[FlightData]    Script Date: 23/06/2017 1:21:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FlightData](
    [FlighID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [FlightNo] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [FlightDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [FlightTypeID] [int] NULL,
    [AirLineID] [int] NULL,
    [Arrival] [time](7) NULL,
    [Departure] [time](7) NULL,
    [AdultPrice] [money] NULL,
    [ChildPrice] [money] NULL,
    [Stock] [int] NULL,
    [TotalPrice] [money] NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_FlightData_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [FlighID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[FlightRoute]    Script Date: 23/06/2017 1:21:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FlightRoute](
    [FlightTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FlightFrom] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [FlightTo] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_FlightType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [FlightTypeID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Hotel]    Script Date: 23/06/2017 1:21:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Hotel](
    [ProductID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProductName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [BestimmingID] [int] NULL,
    [TypeID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Product] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ProductID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[HotelPrice]    Script Date: 23/06/2017 1:21:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HotelPrice](
    [ProductPriceID] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [ProductID] [int] NULL,
    [FromDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ToDate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ProductPrice] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ProductPriceID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Luggage]    Script Date: 23/06/2017 1:21:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Luggage](
    [LuggageID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AirLineID] [int] NULL,
    [KG] [float] NULL,
    [CostPrice] [int] NULL,
    [SalesPrice] [int] NULL,
    [LuggageName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Luggage] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [LuggageID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Parent]    Script Date: 23/06/2017 1:21:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Parent](
    [ParentID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Subject] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Text] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Slug] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Parent] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ParentID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[RoomOccupation]    Script Date: 23/06/2017 1:21:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RoomOccupation](
    [RoomOccupationID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OccupationNo] [int] NULL,
    [MaxAdult] [int] NULL,
    [MaxOccupation] [int] NULL,
    [Price] [money] NULL,
    [ProductID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_RoomOccupation] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RoomOccupationID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[RoomService]    Script Date: 23/06/2017 1:21:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RoomService](
    [RoomServiceID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoomService] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ProductID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_RoomService] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RoomServiceID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[RoomType]    Script Date: 23/06/2017 1:21:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RoomType](
    [RoomTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RoomType] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ProductID] [int] NULL,
    [RoomPrice] [money] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_RoomType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RoomTypeID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Services]    Script Date: 23/06/2017 1:21:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Services](
    [ServiceID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ServiceType] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ProductID] [int] NULL,
    [ServicePrice] [money] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Services] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ServiceID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Tour]    Script Date: 23/06/2017 1:21:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tour](
    [PackageID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PackageName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [BestimID] [int] NULL,
    [Duration] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Package] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PackageID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TourDestination]    Script Date: 23/06/2017 1:21:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TourDestination](
    [PackageID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BestomingID] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TourDuration]    Script Date: 23/06/2017 1:21:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TourDuration](
    [PackageDurationsID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PackageID] [int] NULL,
    [PackageDuration] [int] NULL,
    [NightCounts] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PackageDuration] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PackageDurationsID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TourType]    Script Date: 23/06/2017 1:21:01 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TourType](
    [PackageTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PackageType] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PackageType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PackageTypeID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ActivityType]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ActivityType_Product] FOREIGN KEY([ProductID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Hotel] ([ProductID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ActivityType] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ActivityType_Product]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ChildrenDiscount]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ChildrenDiscount_Product] FOREIGN KEY([ProductID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Hotel] ([ProductID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ChildrenDiscount] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ChildrenDiscount_Product]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DurationDetails]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_DurationDetails_PackageDuration] FOREIGN KEY([PackageDurationsID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TourDuration] ([PackageDurationsID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DurationDetails] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_DurationDetails_PackageDuration]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FlightData]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_FlightData_AirLine] FOREIGN KEY([AirLineID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AirLine] ([AirLineID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FlightData] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_FlightData_AirLine]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[HotelPrice]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ProductPrice_Product] FOREIGN KEY([ProductID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Hotel] ([ProductID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[HotelPrice] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ProductPrice_Product]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Luggage]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Luggage_AirLine] FOREIGN KEY([AirLineID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AirLine] ([AirLineID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Luggage] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Luggage_AirLine]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RoomOccupation]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_RoomOccupation_Product] FOREIGN KEY([ProductID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Hotel] ([ProductID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RoomOccupation] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_RoomOccupation_Product]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RoomService]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_RoomService_Product] FOREIGN KEY([ProductID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Hotel] ([ProductID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RoomService] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_RoomService_Product]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RoomType]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_RoomType_Product] FOREIGN KEY([ProductID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Hotel] ([ProductID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RoomType] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_RoomType_Product]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TourDestination]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_PackageBestim_Bestiming] FOREIGN KEY([BestomingID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Destination] ([BestimID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TourDestination] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_PackageBestim_Bestiming]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TourDestination]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_PackageBestim_Package] FOREIGN KEY([PackageID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Tour] ([PackageID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TourDestination] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_PackageBestim_Package]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TourDuration]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_PackageDuration_Package] FOREIGN KEY([PackageID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Tour] ([PackageID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TourDuration] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_PackageDuration_Package]
GO
```

**Update Original post**
can you see this image below
this is show that calculate based on fixed program

[How calculation done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYpjj.jpg)

Comment: The data you are showing for Table Tour Duration Details and Table cost Per day are for tour #1 only, correct?

Comment: Flight prices and hotel prices change over time. So is this tour only valid for a certain time and once one of the prices changes, you invalidate tour #1 and create a similar new tour? Or how do you plan to go about this?

Comment: yes for tour 1 only

Comment: flight prices and hotel prices changes over time or period this is correct as example room price in month january different in price from month augest

Comment: also every tour have more periods tourq1 as example may have two periods period 3 period 6 and table details get details for every period that related to tour

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a table for the tour duration. First of all you could have put the number of days just in the `tour` table, but even this would be a bad idea, as the number of days is already implicitly given by the records in table `Tour Duration Details`.

The prices changing over time are another thing to consider. One possible model is this:

- **tour** (tour_no, description)
- **flight** (flight_id, from_city, to_city)
- **flight_price** (flight_id, from_date, to_date, price)
- **hotel** (hotel_id, name)
- **hotel_price** (hotel_id, from_date, to_date, price)
- **tour_days** (tour_no, day_no, flight_id, hotel_id)

Now let's say someone wants to book tour #1 starting 2017-08-25. The query to calculate the cost would be:

```
select coalesce(sum(fp.price), 0) + coalesce(sum(hp.price), 0)
from tour_days d
left join flight f on f.flight_id = d.flight_id
left join flight_price fp on fp.flight_id = f.flight_id
                          and date '2017-08-25' between fp.from_date and fp.to_date
left join hotel h on h.hotel_id = d.hotel_id
left join hotel_price hp on hp.hotel_id = h.hotel_id
                         and date '2017-08-25' between hp.from_date and hp.to_date
where d.tour_no = 1;
```

Comment: thank you for reply calculation based on detail duration table

Comment: can you please see image in original post